# How can you style/modify django file fields?

Tags: html, css, django

In my django (1.6) project, I have a form with a FileField for uploading images (It is a FileField and not an ImageField for legacy reasons).

Currently I render the form field in a template by doing {{ form.image }} which renders it with the label, link to the image, clearing checkbox and upload button. This is all good, but I need to style those separate modules.

For the url, I'd like to make it render as:

```
<a href="url" class="fancybox" rel="group">
   <img src="url" alt="product image" class="img-responsive">
</a>
```

And for the other parts (buttons, checkbox), I want to add CSS classes to them.

I looked at the ClearableFileInput widged which is responsible for rendering the FileField and I am thinking maybe I can achieve this by overriding some methods, but I am not sure what to override to change as little as possible.

How can I achieve this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The widget accepts an `attrs` parameter. It's a dictionary that is passed along to be the attributes on the rendered HTML widget. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs).

Here's the example from the docs with the class specified:

```
name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Your name', 'class': 'img-responsive'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want build custom widget - you can inherit it from `ClearableFileInput` override  `render` method and specify custom `template_with_initial`, it is quite simple